# Declaring variable length array in a class

Tags: class, variable-length-array

folks. Here's my piece of code:

```
class Solar_system
{
    public:

    Solar_system()
    {
        planet_no = 5;
    }

    int planet_no;
    int planet[planet_no];
};
```

Error given: invalid use of non-static data member `Solar_system::planet_no`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What have you tried to remedy the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming this is in C++.

When creating an array at run time it should be dynamically allocated.  Like this:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

So you would create a pointer in the class and then set the array up:

```
int * planet;
int planet_no;
Solar_system()
{
    planet_no = 5;
    planet = new int[planet_no];
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me if the array should afterwards be deleted, and if so when.

Comment: Yes, it should be deleted. The class destructor is a good place to delete it.  ~Solar_system(){ delete [] planet;} That way it is always called.  If you need to resize/recreate the array you would delete it before setting it to a new block of memory as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing your own memory management, use a suitable container. For example, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

```
class Solar_system {
public:

    Solar_system()
    {
        planets_.resize(5);
    }

    std::vector<int> planets_;
};
```